# fetching list of reports using @wire in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to fetch report list using `wire`.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api} from 'lwc';
import REPORT_OBJECT  from '@salesforce/schema/Report';
import {getListUi} from 'lightning/uiListApi';
export default class cmpReportList extends LightningElement {
@wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: REPORT_OBJECT,listViewApiName: 'All'})
wiredlistView({error,data}) {
    if (data) {
        this.allreports = data.records;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
}
```

But I am getting error while pushing the code `No MODULE named markup://lightning:getListUi found`. This might be because `lightning:uiListApi` is probably still in beta.

Is there any other way to fetch list without using `apex method`

Comment: Is it happening bcoz you are trying to access Reports? Did you check for other Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the RecordUI API docs, Report is not in the supported object list, so you can't return the list.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add `this.allreports = data.records.records`

and i am importing - `import {getListUi} from 'lightning/uiListApi';`

This code is working for me -

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    wire,
    track
} from 'lwc';
import {
    getListUi
} from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class ListUI extends LightningElement {
    @track sobjectResult;
    @wire(getListUi, {
        objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT,
        listViewApiName: 'All'
    })
    wiredlistView({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.sobjectResult = data.records.records;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the [Link](https://rajvakati.com/2019/01/28/getlistui-wire-adapter/) for your Reference

Hope this will work for you, kindly let me know if you still find an error.

Comment: I made change but still does not work for me.  Were you able to push this code using VS code? I am getting error mentioned in the question while pushing code to source org itself.

Comment: Note that uiListApi (official documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-ui-list-api/documentation) - I suggest always providing links to official documentation rather than third-party material where possible) is still in Beta.

Comment: Yeah, It is still in beta. Even if it works in dev org, it cannot be deployed to PROD.